# C# Generic Search Helper

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to rewrite a Search helper using generics instead of what I have below, two identical methods except for the type of list being passed in. When I add `<T>` to the class and then insert `<T>` into the Type declaration of each of the lists, I get the following error:

The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ProjectName.Helpers.Extensions.AttributeExtensions.GetDescription(T)'

```
public class SearchFilterHelper
{
    public static SelectList GenreSelectList(List<GenreFilter> filters, int selectedValue = 0)
    {
        var GenreList = filters.Select(g => new { Value = g.ToString(), Description = g.GetDescription() });
        return new SelectList(GeneratedList, "Value", "Description", selectedValue.ToString());
    }

    public static SelectList PublisherSelectList(List<PublisherFilter> filters, int selectedValue = 0)
    {
        var GeneratedList = filters.Select(g => new { Value = g.ToString(), Description = g.GetDescription() });
        return new SelectList(GeneratedList, "Value", "Description", selectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt at using Generics in a Helper and any help in understanding how to rewrite this is, as always, appreciated...

Comment: Cannot help you if I don't know what GenreFilter and PublisherFilter are made of

Comment: Genre Filter and PublisherFIlter are both from enums, the format of whcih is below:

`public enum GenreFilter
    {
        FamilyLife = 1,
        Fitness = 2,
        Children = 3,
        Computer = 4,
        Cooking = 5,
        SelfHelp = 6,
        Business = 7,
        Literature = 8
    }`

Comment: That's a ton of custom types. You will need to include them, it's hard to make something more generic when you don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetDescription` method you have applies the generic constraint that the generic argument be a `struct`.  If you want to call that method from yours, you'll need to apply that same generic constraint.

Comment: Are you meaning something like this: `g.GetDescription<T>()`? in which case I am still getting the same error, so I am guessing that I am not understanding what you mean correctly.

Comment: I finally got what you meant ... Thanks Servy